# PHP login cookie not recognized after a couple hours, but nonetheless remains, and cannot be replaced, even after deleted

Tags: php, validation, cookies, setcookie

I'm new to PHP, but not programming overall, and this has had me stumped for a few weeks now.

I'm working on a website where the login will start to be used by others so I can't use my workaround at that point.

This is the code to set the cookie.

```
ob_start();

...

session_register("myusername");

session_register("mypassword");

$cookiename = "loginsuccess";

$ipforcookie = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$cookiedata = $myusername._.$ipforcookie;

$cookietime = time()+18000;

setcookie($cookiename, $cookiedata, $cookietime, '/', ".example.com");

...

ob_end_flush();
```

This is the code I use to check if the cookie is valid.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['loginsuccess'])){

    $arr = explode("_", $_COOKIE['loginsuccess']);

    if(strcmp($arr[1], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == 0){

        require("headerLogged.php");

    }else{

        require("header.php");

    }

}else{

    require("header.php");

}
```

It checks if there is a cookie, and if the IP is match, in case someone tries to copy the cookie over to their computer or basic like that.

The problem is, I can login and the cookie is registered everywhere that i check for it... for about two hours. Then the website stops accepting it, and even after i delete the cookie, it will not create a new cookie unless i change the function call from...

```
setcookie($cookiename, $cookiedata, $cookietime, '/', ".example.com");
```

to

```
setcookie($cookiename, $cookiedata, $cookietime, '/');
```

Then the login and validation works again. Repeating as necessary every 2 hours. I can't do this any longer, because others will begin using this login without the knowledge I have of the code, or access to the site.

Edit: When i changed it to the later just now, it could be validated, but only on the part of the site that it was created (somewhat obviously, perhaps).

I hope I've given you enough information, and I appreciate any help you're willing to give me, related to this issue, because I'm sure even the small amount of code I've supplied reveals my novice status. In any case, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using PHP sessions? You've got the `session_register()` calls (which are deprecrated, by the way, and should be avoided), but I don't see a `session_start()` anywhere.

Your login system is highly flawed, however. Remember that cookies are stored on the client-side of things. Simply embedding an IP address into the cookie doesn't keep anyone out. They can simply edit the cookie on their side to match their IP address and **boom**, they're into your system.

Use regular PHP sessions instead.

Comment: `session_register()` does an implicit call to `session_start()` if a session has not been started, so the missing call should not cause problems (but `session_register()` is deprecated and should not be used in the first place, we both agree on that).

Answer (score 0):

First, `session_register()` is deprecated since PHP 5.3.0 and should not be used any more. You should use the superglobal `$_SESSION` instead. See the PHP manpages for more information.

Also just checking whether or not a cookie has some value is not sufficient to secure your site. It is rather easy to fake a cookie in a browser, and the contents of cookies should be treated as any other user input (which means you should not assume it meets your expectations, you cannot be sure it even contains an underscore). Based on a mock cookie I should never get access to any parts of your site that require login.

A cookie could contain some session id value, and the session itself then contains further information about who's logged in (user_id, but **no password**). You also could use a cookie that contains the user_id and use that as extra verification. Never store any password in cookies or sessions.